# SharePoint 2010 GetListItems - Problem with CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml, soap

This works

```
"<Where>" +
    "<And>" +
        "<Geq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name=\"StartDate\"/>" +
            "<Value Type=\"Date\">" +
                DateTime.Now.Date.FirstBusinessDayOfWeek().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + 
            "</Value>" +
        "</Geq>" +
        "<Leq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name=\"DueDate\"/>" +
            "<Value Type=\"Date\">" +
                DateTime.Now.Date.LastBusinessDayOfWeek().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + 
            "</Value>" +
        "</Leq>" +
    "</And>" +
"</Where>"
```

This does not

```
"<Where>" +
    "<And>" +
        "<Geq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name=\"StartDate\"/>" +
            "<Value Type=\"Date\">" +
                DateTime.Now.Date.FirstBusinessDayOfWeek().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + 
            "</Value>" +
        "</Geq>" +
        "<Leq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name=\"DueDate\"/>" +
            "<Value Type=\"Date\">" +
                DateTime.Now.Date.LastBusinessDayOfWeek().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + 
            "</Value>" +
        "</Leq>" +
        "<Eq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name=\"MasterTaskID\"/>" +
            "<Value Type=\"Text\">" +
            "t4" + 
            "</Value>" +
        "</Eq>" +
    "</And>" +
"</Where>"
```

Including the filter criteria for MasterTaskID results in a SOAP exception being thrown.

Can anyone spot what is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query.

If you're not familiar with CAML, you could use [caml designer](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/new-version-of-the-caml-designer-released/) to help you building the caml query.

```
"<Where>" +
    "<And>" +
    "<And>" +
        "<Geq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name=\"StartDate\"/>" +
            "<Value Type=\"Date\">" +
                DateTime.Now.Date.FirstBusinessDayOfWeek().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + 
            "</Value>" +
        "</Geq>" +
        "<Leq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name=\"DueDate\"/>" +
            "<Value Type=\"Date\">" +
                DateTime.Now.Date.LastBusinessDayOfWeek().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + 
            "</Value>" +
        "</Leq>" +
    "</And>" +  
        "<Eq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name=\"MasterTaskID\"/>" +
            "<Value Type=\"Text\">" +
            "t4" + 
            "</Value>" +
        "</Eq>" +
    "</And>" +
"</Where>"
```

Comment: Thanks Lee! I'll check out the caml designer, I am somewhat new to  caml. I need a facepalm emoji